# Получить HTML структуру файла в PYTHON

Tags: python, сокет

Задача. Используя сокеты получить html и поместить его в переменную.Столкнулся с ошибкой, не знаю как решить. Надеюсь, на вашу помощь.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.tafensw.edu.au\r\n\r\n"
s.connect(("www.tafensw.edu.au", 80))
s.sendall(request.encode())
contest = s.recv(1024).decode()
s.close()
print(contest)
```

Результат

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved permanently
Location: https://www.tafensw.edu.au/
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не ошибка, а редирект:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301

По всей видимости, сайт не поддерживает HTTP, только HTTPS. Пытаться получить информацию с помощью прямого соединения через сокет - очень похоже на самоубийство, потому что Вам потребуется установить HTTPS-туннель и обрабатывать шифрование, не надо так :)

Попробуйте библиотеку *requests*:
https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

И код будет примерно такой:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.tafensw.edu.au/')
print(r.text)
```

P.S. Ну а если прям вот надо через сокеты, то ищите другой ресурс, который работает через HTTP и никуда не редиректит)